# Proper way to include C++ system headers when using g++-arm-linux-gnueabi?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a library on Ubuntu 14.04 with packages `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` and `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` installed.

The compile fails on the first source file it encounters:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -I. -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM 
-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi -c 3way.cpp
In file included from cryptlib.h:83:0,
                 from seckey.h:8,
                 from 3way.h:7,
                 from 3way.cpp:5:
stdcpp.h:14:18: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

When I perform a `find` I see that the C++ headers are located at:

```
$ find /usr -name memory
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/tr1/memory
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/memory
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/ext/memory
...
```

`/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi` is already provided as `SYSROOT`:

```
$ ls /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
bin  include  lib
```

Adding an `isysroot` does not help:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -isysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3
--sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi -c 3way.cpp
In file included from cryptlib.h:83:0,
                 from seckey.h:8,
                 from 3way.h:7,
                 from 3way.cpp:5:
stdcpp.h:14:18: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
```

I've cross compiled the library on other platforms (like Android, iOS and Windows Phone), so I have a good idea of what needs to be done. This is my first time with `arm-linux-gnueabi`, however.

What is the proper way to include C++ headers and libraries when using the `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` package?

Related: shouldn't a `spec` file already handle this?

---

**EDIT**: here's some related information with `-v`. These built-in paths look unhealthy. It looks like the toolchain is trying to form the path to the C++ headers, but its not doing a good job:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM 
-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi -c 3way.cpp

...
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3"
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi/sf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) version 4.7.3 (arm-linux-gnueabi)
...
```

---

**Edit**: this looks like a bug in the internal paths used by the toolchain. In the built-in paths, notice there's an extra `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi` in the path. The answer below provides a workaround.

Bug report filed with Ubuntu: [g++-arm-linux-gnueabi cannot compile a C++ program with --sysroot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross/+bug/1375071).

Comment: What is your target CPU You're using linux compiler, but -mcpu=cortex-m3, which is not very likely to run Linux at least not a full featured version. Take a look at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and configure it for proper target.

Comment: @yegorich - thanks (I forgot about uclib and buildroot). This is a test at the moment, so I can choose any CPU for testing. Its a test because I'm focusing on the procedure, and not the CPU. What CPU would you suggest for `arm-linux-gnueabi`?

Comment: Try with `--sysroot /usr` instead of `--sysroot=/usr` ?  You've got equal signs in the paths, that definitely shouldn't be...

Comment: Thanks @Ben. - No joy when omitting the equal sign. The issue still exists. I took at quick look at the [GCC man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) page, and its shows the equal sign. I updated the bug report just in case, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi/sf"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/backward"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/usr/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/include
>  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/include-fixed
>  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include
> End of search list.
> GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) version 4.7.3 (arm-linux-gnueabi)
> ...
> ```

---

This looks like a bug in the internal paths used by the toolchain. In the built-in paths, notice there's an extra `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi` in the path. Bug report filed with Ubuntu: [g++-arm-linux-gnueabi cannot compile a C++ program with --sysroot](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross/+bug/1375071).

To work around the bug, the paths to the C++ headers should be added explicitly with `-I`:

- `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3`
- `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi`

There's no need to specify the C and C++ libraries when linking with `--sysroot` because the option handles them properly.

So a compile/link command would look similar to:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ ... -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb \
  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 \
  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi \
  --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi test.cpp -o test.exe
```